# How to use a pipe | as part of an SQL query in VBA access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, pipe

There is a recordset in my access DB that has a field called "OperationDesc" that stores strings that contain the pipe ("|") character.  Whenever I use the VBA SQL methods to search through my recordset to identify a particular string that has the pipe character in it - I  get an error 3077 "Invalid use of vertical bars in expression.

The section that brings about the error is this:

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
qr = "SELECT * FROM [A500Constants] ORDER BY [A500Constants].[ID];"
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(qr)
qr = "[A500Constants].[ID] = " & Me.Controls("AddRoutDesc" & spot).Value
**rs.FindFirst qr**

If rs.Fields("ID") = 1 And Not rs.Fields("OperationDesc") = Me.Controls("AddRoutDesc" & CStr(spot)).Value Then
    'If true at start of rs when not suppose to be - signifies new entry time
    'if Me.Controls("AddRoutDesc" & CStr(Spot)).Value returned a description rather than ID the If would evaluate properly for the 1st item on the routing too
    'beginning process of validating new operation data
```

The programs bugs out at "rs.FindFirst qr" when Me.Controls("AddRoutDesc" & spot).Value is a string containing a | pipe character.

**What this is trying to do:**  There are n number of combo boxes with the naming convention AddRoutDesc0, AddRoutDesc1, .... and from there I am allowing the user to enter any text s/he wishes.  Upon leaving the combobox, I search through a table/recordset by a column titled "OperationDesc" to see if this description has been used before.  (I know that I'm currently searching on the ID - I would like to search on the OperationDesc field as it is the only way to allow the user to enter new descriptions at the same time b/c of a conflict between multicolumn comboboxes and the link to list property.)  The comboboxes are populated with prior descriptions to choose from, some of which have the pipe | character.  This error comes about when I have selected such a description and am leaving the combobox which runs the above.  If there is some easier method - I'm all ears or if anyone knows **how to get SQL to see a pipe as just another part of a string**, that'd be perfect.

I currently have the following code ready and it works to search for a | (or anything really) and replace it with some additional delimiter and the pipe to make it not flag w/e in SQL.

```
Private Function SQLStringFixer(InputString As String, ByVal FindString As String, ByVal ReplacementString As String, ByVal CompType As Integer) As String
   If Not IsNull(InputString) Then
        Dim WorkingStr As String
        Dim Pntr As Integer

        WorkingStr = InputString
        Pntr = InStr(1, WorkingStr, FindString, CompType)

        Do While Pntr > 0
            WorkingStr = Left(CStr(WorkingStr), CLng(Pntr - 1)) & ReplacementString & Mid(WorkingStr, Pntr + Len(FindString))
            Pntr = InStr(Pntr + Len(ReplacementString), WorkingStr, FindString, CompType)
        Loop
        SQLStringFixer = WorkingStr
    Else
        SQLStringFixer = ""
    End If
End Function

Private Function FixStr4JetSQL(InputString As String) As String
     Dim Temp As String
     Temp = SQLStringFixer(InputString, "'", "''", vbBinaryCompare)
     FixStr4JetSQL = SQLStringFixer(Temp, "|", "' & chr(124) & '", vbBinaryCompare)
End Function
```

I ultimately just need to know what characters or set of characters will let a query in SQL see a | pipe as a pipe and not some key-symbol to do w/e.  If anyone knows what this is - it will be a big help - such a trivial matter has cost me so much time.

Comment: `qr = "[A500Constants].[ID] = " & Me.Controls("AddRoutDesc" & spot).Value` Shouldn't you be putting quotes around the expression with the pipe?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a single field filled with multiple descriptions? This looks very like a design fault. You could save yourself a great deal of trouble by having a description table with single lines for each description ( http://r937.com/relational.html ). Why are you using FindFirst rather than appending a WHERE statement to your SQL? I am puzzled as to how this works at all, when you have not use LIKE.

Comment: @Remou Who has time for a proper relational model? I'm using a RAD tool! We'll always be able to *rapidly* change it later, right?

Comment: @ta.speot.is I am suggesting a *faster* approach to the design than writing code. What makes Access a RAD tool is that you can mostly avoid code. The key point was "save yourself a great deal of trouble".

Comment: ok I just changed the line to:  
qr = "[A500Constants].[OperationDesc] = """ & Me.Controls("AddRoutDesc" & spot).Value & """"
rs.FindFirst qr
it now works... I swear to God - I did this yesterday and it didn't work... maybe there is something wrong with my work comp - thanks for the pro tip cause apparently that is all I needed to do

Comment: I did have a combobox with multiple columns, basically it would display a description but the value property would be an associated ID number, so that combobox would be locked to only having values in it from a recordset.  This is what it was doing and not what I wanted to do.  Now that I have the quotes around it - I no longer need the ID number to search through the rows of a recordset when a pipe is in the description.  So now I can have it show the current descriptions avaliable and allow the user to add a new one if he wants - this was my goal and it has worked, thanks. findfirst works =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The programs bugs out at `rs.FindFirst qr` when `Me.Controls("AddRoutDesc" & spot).Value` is a string containing a `|` pipe character.

I am not sure it would work for strings containing anything other than numbers or a SQL keyword like `NULL`.

Consider if `Me.Controls("AddRouteDesc" & spot).Value` contains `iamastringwithoutapipe`. The line:

```
qr = "[A500Constants].[ID] = " & Me.Controls("AddRoutDesc" & spot).Value
```

is equivalent to:

```
qr = "[A500Constants].[ID] = " & "iamastringwithoutapipe"
```

is equivalent to:

```
qr = "[A500Constants].[ID] = iamastringwithoutapipe"
```

I would think the correct statement would be:

```
qr = "[A500Constants].[ID] = '" & Me.Controls("AddRoutDesc" & spot).Value & "'"
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
qr = "[A500Constants].[ID] = 'iamastringwithoutapipe'"
```

On the whole, using `FindFirst` like this [is quite fragile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113955). You'd probably be better off writing a handful of [parameterised queries](http://www.a1vbcode.com/vbtip-28.asp) and/or not using Access.

Comment: Why not use Access? Let us say this is a small business, Access is the cheap, sensible choice and always has been. Almost anything is 'fragile' if you are not using it properly. Parameter queries are a great idea, but they take time, and sometimes that time is not available, after all Access is a [RAD tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437387/is-ms-access-still-the-most-efficient-rad-tool-for-small-scale-custom-apps).

Comment: @Remou `"probably be better off not using Access" != "do not use Access"`

Comment: I tried qr = "[A500Constants].[ID] = '" & Me.Controls("AddRoutDesc" & spot).Value & "'" and that doesn't work, you were right with your comment earlier that it is qr = "[A500Constants].[OperationDesc] = """ & Me.Controls("AddRoutDesc" & spot).Value & """"